# Solaris 10: Drop disk cache? (to benchmark app)

Tags: performance, solaris, hard-drive, benchmark, disk-cache

Is there a command to drop the ZFS and UFS disk caches? (Preferably just one folder hierarchy.)

I'm trying to tuning the performance settings of an application that read/writes data from a large number of files. Mostly read.

In actual use, the app will only run once in a while so the files in question will not likely be cached.

However, since I am testing multiple times in a row, Solaris is trying to be helpful by keeping this files in memory.

Between benchmark runs, can I instruct Solaris to drop anything under `/path/to/data` from it's caches?

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you seeing performance problems and want to see if the cache in memory is the culprit?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to selectively drop the cache per directory.

For a whole file system, running `lockfs -f /directory` will flush all of this directory file system cached data on disk.

If for some reason, this doesn't have the wanted effect, a more radical way is to unmount/remount the filesystem (UFS) and export/import the pool (ZFS).